# AWS ec2-user vs regular users and access to GPU

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cuda, gpu

Let's say we have an AWS instance with GPU capability. Also, only ec2-user/root users can install software on this server (nvidia drivers, CUDA, etc..). Now suppose ec2-user/root user types the command `nvidia-smi` and receives the following output:

[image]

Would a "regular" (non-root user or non ec2-user) user still get the same output? Or would he get something like `NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn’t communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running`?

In other words, do regular users also have access to the GPU/CUDA if it has been installed by the root/ec2-user?

Comment: Have you tested it? It looks like you can answer your own question with a quick test

Answer (score 2):

Yes, regular users should have access to GPU/CUDA, if you have not done anything unusual during the install.  The only way you would get this kind of behavior mismatch (between root and ordinary user) would be if you had modified permissions on the [device files](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#runfile-verifications).  However a typical install will set permissions so that anyone can use the GPUs.

However even in the case where the device permissions are set in an unusual way, the difference would not result in that particular error message for the ordinary user, it would result in a permissions message.

That particular error message indicates a broken driver install, and the broken driver install will manifest itself for both root and ordinary users.

Note that the "broken driver install" statement here assumes you have already rebooted the instance, and are still seeing the message.  If you have not yet rebooted the instance after driver install, that is recommended.